# What should I do if my z-statistic/t-statistic can't be found in Z/T-tables?

Tags: statistics

If my test statistics are too large, for instance: t(n-1=20)=100, what should I say about p-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should say its significant. If its off the chart then it will exceed even the stringent p=.001 significance level. However, it should also lead you to possibly check the unerlying data to ensure its approximately normally distributed and that you don't have any outliers. The t-test is sensitive to violations of normality in the underlying data.